# Rails: redirect_to with :error, but flash[:error] empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to do a redirect while setting the flash[:error] value. (Rails 3.0.10)

In my view I have

```
<p id="error"><%= flash[:error] %></p>
<p id="notice"><%= flash[:notice] %></p>
```

If I do a `redirect_to show_path, :notice => "ok"` it works fine, but if I do `redirect_to show_path, :error => "error"` it doesn't show up.

what could I be missing?

Answer (score 250, accepted):

As stated in the [Rails API](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#the-flash) only :notice and :alert are by default applied as a flash hash value. If you need to set the :error value, you can do it like this:

```
redirect_to show_path, flash: { error: "Insufficient rights!" }
```

Comment: For clarity: `redirect_to(show_path, {:flash => { :error => "Insufficient rights!" }})`. This format is needed if you want to create show_path with url options.

Comment: That worked for me too, I just wonder what the thought was behind only notice/alert being in the flash hash

Comment: Worked in Rails 5

Comment: You can move away from ruby 1.9 format to: `redirect_to(show_path, flash: { error: "Insufficient rights!" })`

Answer (score 17):

If you are having problem to keep the flash after redirecting to another path, then use this.

```
flash.keep
```

in your method, before redirecting.

Comment: I just get the following shown in the directed page: ```#<ActionDispatch::Flash::FlashHash:0x007f88c6e0c3c8>
#<ActionDispatch::Flash::FlashHash:0x007f88c6e0c3c8>```

Comment: It seems that it not the answer of the question but it was the solution of my problem!

Answer (score 0):

**controller.rb**

```
flash[:sucess] =  "Your sucess message"
redirect_to action: :index
```

layout.html

```
<% if flash[:sucess] %>
    <div class="alert alert-solid-success alert-bold" role="alert">
        <div class="alert-text"><%= sanitize(flash[:sucess]) %></div>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score -1):

To truly follow the PRG pattern, I wonder if this project works well

https://github.com/tommeier/rails-prg

I can't stand apps not following PRG as a user.....I have been 6 pages after a POST and hit the back button to get back to 10 pages ago get blocked by "do you want to repost this crap"....no, of course not. I just want to get back to a page I had seen before.

non-PRG apps are very very annoying to users.