# flash[:notice] gets erased after redirect_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, flash-message

`flash[:notice]` gets erased as soon as I use `redirect_to` in rails 2.2.2
It's a super simple ruby application, so it shouldn't be to hard to find what's going on (although, I couldn't find it obviously...)

My routes.rb looks like this

```
resources :happenings
root to: "happenings#index"
post "/happenings/save"
```

And my HappeningsController looks like this

```
def index
   @happenings = Happening.all
end

def save
   flash[:notice] = "saved"
   redirect_to root_path
end
```

Now if I'm debugging and I add `puts flash[:notice]` to the save action, it will print "saved" to my terminal
if I add `puts flash[:notice] to the index action, it will print an empty line to the terminal. So it obviously has been erased by the time the index action gets executed.

Any ideas? Thanks a lot?

Edit, Here's a bit more information.
The `save` action get's called by a form

```
<form method="post" action="/happenings/save">
```

The following is the server's output when I submit a form (and request the save action)

```
Started POST "/happenings/save" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-07-02 23:16:31 +0200
Processing by HappeningsController#save as HTML
  Parameters: {"happening_name"=>"Test happening", "happening_time"=>"2015-07-24T13:15"}
Can't verify CSRF token authenticity
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
Completed 302 Found in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)


Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-07-02 23:16:32 +0200
Processing by HappeningsController#index as HTML
  Rendered happenings/index.html.erb within layouts/application (0.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 32ms (Views: 28.4ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Comment: Can you make sure you aren't reseting any cookie from application controller? Because flash messages are stored in cookie. You can also try flash.now[:notice] = '....'

Comment: @sjbuysse I think that you need the [`flash-message`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flash-message) instead of [`flash`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flash) tag, I edited it.

Answer (score 1):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/12340941/2011580
If you are having problem to keep the flash after redirecting to another path, then use this.

flash.keep

in your method, before redirecting.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to do something like this:

```
def save
  redirect_to root_path
  flash[:notice] = "saved"
end
```

And then place

```
<%= flash[:notice] %>
```

anywhere in your index.html.erb.

Comment: That doens't work, just tried it.
Also, I'm wondering if it even makes sense, since you're redirecting to the `root_path` (and leaving the `save` action) before you set the `:notice`

Comment: That will never work. you are getting redirected before setting the flash message.

Answer (score 0):

Can you make sure you aren't reseting any cookie from application controller? Because flash messages are stored in cookie. You can also try

```
flash.now[:notice] = '....'
```

before redirection you can use:

```
flash.keep(:notice)
```

source: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html

A tip:

> You can install a gem named pry. You can set that in your view file
>   when you need, so you can get an interactive shell in your server when
>   the server serve that page. There you can test all your dynamic value
>   carriers. And you can understand whats going on actually.